# Is it possible to transition from EF5 database-first to code-first?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, ef-database-first

I'm about to start on a new project, and while most of my team's experience is with using VS Database projects and SSMS directly on a database, we would like to use EF instead. However, time constraints won't allow us to take the time to fully learn EF before implementation.

At first glance, the code-first migrations in EF Code-first seem like they would be a very valuable tool, but with code-centric database first (they don't seem to have a good name for this) code migrations don't appear to be a feature. Instead, only projects that start as code-first seem to support this.

Is it possible to start with a database, and then (at some point during development), somehow convert to Code-first, in order to take advantage of Code First Migrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [EF Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) (not an 'answer' but something to try and have in mind).

**It has the `Reverse Engineer Code First`** which should create POCO-s etc. for you.

However it is an experimental tool (in Beta), and has a few issues setting up - but you could give it a try.

Other than that - it could be tricky, so it's better you start 'earlier' -
**but IMO there isn't anything that you couldn't actually transfer manually** - at any point - providing your database is not using too much of the 'complex features' and relying on some advanced scenarios.

> Just have in mind some of the limitations that CF imposes (e.g. like
>   having to resort to 'Seed'-ing and manual SQL for complex scenarios,
>   no native support for UDF, stored procedures - but you can still manually specify it...) - so that you avoid
>   basing your Db design on such things - but rather work things 'the
>   code first way' - and possibly adding couple extra manual fixes where
>   needed.

And take a look at this post (links):
[Entity Framework - Reverse Engineer Code First - Overwriting Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826673/entity-framework-reverse-engineer-code-first-overwriting-changes)

http://romiller.com/2012/05/09/customizing-reverse-engineer-code-first-in-the-ef-power-tools/

Comment: Many of the tools from EF Power Tools will be included as part of EF6, and I believe that includes the Reverse Engineer feature.